# Samba share command line question

Tags: virtualbox, samba, cifs

I'm running an Ubuntu server guest with Virtualbox connected via a host-only network to my host which is an ubuntu 19.04 desktop.

I'm looking for a method to use samba shares to mount shared folders from the host via my host-only network to the guest where the commands are run from the host. The host folders need to be mounted to the guest or rather, the hosts data needs to be persistent on the host once the connection is closed.

This is not the standard:

sudo mount -t smbfs -o user=xxx //192.168.xxx.xxx/host-folder /guest-folder

It would be more like:

sudo mount -t smbfs -o user=xxx /guest-folder//192.168.xxx.xxx/host-folder

Naturally, it doesn't work that way.

So, any ideas or suggestions for how to go about this.

To sum up - I need to run a command from the host to mount my host folders to the guest (in order to make the host folders persistent once the virtual server is shutdown

Thanks

ps - you may ask why I don't use the shared folders with virtualbox, the reason is that once they are mounted it causes huge upline permissions issues that I'd rather not get into :)

Comment: I've mounted host Samba shares hosted on the VBox host machine in one of its guests, but only from the guest OS. Are you unable to run the mount command on the guest? Would an ssh command from the host to the guest which runs the mount command be an option?

Comment: Yes, actually that's a great idea thanks.

A part of the restriction (as I am learning about them) is due to loading CIFS to a docker container. Apparently, even if it's via a virtual server - CIFS mounts is by default not allowed and so it doesn't mount regardless of how it's mounted. So apparantly, my fight is with docker to enable mounting CIFS shares - whether it's run via fstab, command or guest or host.

Comment: Not sure about your use case but NFS might be a simpler option if you don't have to interact with Windows.

Comment: NFS works just fine as well. The issue ultimately is down to docker and privileges to run CIFS in the container which by default is not allowed. I'll do some hacking and fairly sure there's a method with an eloquant solution in here somewhere. Thanks all